# Unable to install tensorflow on windows 7

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I'm currently trying to install tensorflow on windows 7 (64 bits). I have python 3.5.2 version (64 bits). I tried to follow the instructions on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows by taping:

```sh
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow in the cmd.
```

I had the error below:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
>   from versions.  No matching distributions found from tensorflow.

I tried the other way using a wheel file that I downloaded from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow/1.0.1 :

```sh
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64
```

or

```sh
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64
```

They both don't work and it gives me now:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
>   from versions. No matching distributions found for wheel from
>   tensorflow

Could someone help me please?!!!

Comment: if you have downloaded the wheel file tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64 then try pip3 install tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64, If you want tot download tensorflow then don't put the entire name in the cmd

Comment: If you do `pip3 -V` in the command line, what do you see? If you have multiple python versions installed, pip3 might be part of a different python version than you think it is.  It also might be worth moving to anaconda.  It'll let you get venvs set up and try different python versions more easily.

Comment: I put pip3 -V in the cmd and I got: 

pip 8.1.1 from C:\Python35\lib\site-packages <python 3.5>

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading pip3 to recent version and install using
{pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow}