# Tensorflow Installation Unresponsive on Windows 7

Tags: tensorflow, pip, python-3.5, windows-7-x64

I am trying to install Tensorflow (CPU-only) on Windows 7 (64-bit) using native pip installation as per https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows.

First, I downloaded Python 3.5.2 (64-bit). This was successful.

Then, I tried issuing the appropriate command (in cmd):

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

A quick flash of a new window and then...nothing. No errors or timeouts, not even the standard "Collecting tensorflow", just a blinking cursor. This cmd window cannot be closed and stays active until my system is shut down.

I then tried the following:

```
python -m pip install tensorflow
```

It looked promising for a few moments.

```
Collecting tensorflow
```

But then:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('timed out',))':/simple/tensorflow/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('timed out',))':/simple/tensorflow/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('timed out',))':/simple/tensorflow/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('timed out',))':/simple/tensorflow/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('timed out',))':/simple/tensorflow/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I could close this window afterwards.

I have also tried the following:

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

It results in the same problem as before. A blinking cursor, cannot close the window, stays active until shut down.

Found another method on [Unable to install tensorflow on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46475264/unable-to-install-tensorflow-on-windows-7). Downloaded said wheel file and ran as follows:

```
python -m pip install tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Again, looked promising but came back with Proxy Errors. So I tried disabling my antivirus and ran again. FINALLY, SOMETHING NEW! Connection Timeout Errors. Hopefully a step in the right direction?!

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that it was my proxy settings that were interfering with the installation so I changed those.

I then downloaded the required .whl files from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow/1.0.1

```
wheel;
six (>=1.10.0);
protobuf (>=3.1.0);
numpy (>=1.11.0);
and mock (>=2.0.0)
```

After saving these .whl files in the correct folder, I ran this in cmd (with my antivirus disabled):

```
python -m pip install tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Six, protobuf, numpy, mock, and tensorflow successfully installed.

Installation was verified by:

```
python

import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello!')
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(hello)
```